# How to fix lxpanel showing wifi twice?

Tags: wireless, 18.04, lubuntu, broadcom, lxpanel

If I click System Tools > Fcitx and click the keyboard, my computer will freeze until I kill lxpanel, and my wifi is showing twice, as shown in the following image. I will ask how to fix Fcitx in a separate question, but for this question: How do I fix lxpanel showing wifi twice?

[image: taskbar showing wifi icon/applet twice]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1776748) that ultimately lies in the fact that the `lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin` shipped with `lxpanel` is trying to do the job of all other indicators (read: system tray icons). It does create conflicts with more than just networking and may also be the cause of your issues with `fcitx`.

The solution: remove the plugin:

1. Open a terminal and run `lxpanelctl config`
2. Click on the "Panel Applets" tab.
3. In the "Currently loaded plugins," click on "Indicator applets."
4. Click the "Remove" button.
5. Click the "Close" button.
6. Log out/in.

In lieu of the logout, you may need to restart `nm-applet`, `fcitx`, and optionally add the "Volume Control" plugin. Potentially more depending on what indicators the plugin was trying to manage.

Note this works on LXDE, so is only applicable to Lubuntu ≤ 18.04. Also note that previous versions have had issues with multiple icons due to `nm-applet` being launched more than once, which is obviously not the same situation.